# Cassandra hardware configuration

Tags: database, cassandra, cpu-usage

I have a question regarding hardware related performance issues.

Our cassandra nodes had 4 cores with 2GB RAM and we suffered with unreasonable response time (1.5 seconds average on read for 200 calls / sec).

We then upgraded the machines to 8 cores with 8GB RAM and immediately saw an improvement (around 300ms now).

However server analytics doesn't show any peek or extra use of cpu power.

How can this be explained? does an upgrade from 4 cores to 8 cores explain such a performance boost even if it seems like the server's cpu usage is unaffected?

Thanks

Comment: How much memory did you give to JVM?

Comment: JVM is currently at 2GB

Comment: Did you respect this ratio (1/4) when having only 2 gigabytes?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra needs more memory to hold data in memtables and for faster read response times.

8GB to 16GB is what we assign to Cassandra process with JVM parameters tweaked, with 4 CPUs each quad-core so 16 cores per node with sata drives.

Make sure commit log and data dir are on separate disks.

Comment: 8GB is good, but more than 8GB and [GC will start getting slow](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/tuning#heap-sizing).

Comment: It's important to distinguish between ram-per-machine (the more the better) and jvm-heap-per-machine (the 8GB limit).  Generally, you can let Cassandra set the jvm heap automatically and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you left configuration parameters by default, you saw an improvement in performance **partly** because your key cache is now larger.

`key_cache_size_in_mb = (min(5% of Heap (in MB), 100MB))`

`cassandra-env.sh` automatically decide how much heap to give to the JVM (if you did not change it):

```
set max heap size based on the following
max(min(1/2 ram, 1024MB), min(1/4 ram, 8GB))
calculate 1/2 ram and cap to 1024MB
calculate 1/4 ram and cap to 8192MB
pick the max
```

Since your max heap size was increased, your key cache was increased as well.